# Getting PSKeywords while trying to convert pdf to text through pdfminer python library

Tags: python, pdfminer

I am trying to convert a pdf file to .txt file using python pdfminer libary. I am getting the below error -

**TypeError: int() argument must be a string or a number, not 'PSKeyword'**

Please find the attached screen shot for the reference.[error screenshot link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZAQH6.png)

Comment: Edit your Question and add your code relevant to the Error and the full Traceback.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this? I have encountered it too.